# JSON to model avoid exceptions for items

Tags: java, android, json

i tryed to parse JSONObject and save it to custom model. i cannot be sure that all nodes comes in JSONObject, so i check every item:

```
    try {
        object.setId(jsonObject.getInt(ID));
    } catch (JSONException e) {}

    try {
        object.setParentId(jsonObject.getInt(PARENT_ID));
    } catch (JSONException e) {}

    try {
        object.setIsActive(jsonObject.getBoolean(IS_ACTIVE));
    } catch (JSONException e) {}

   .... and ect.
```

is there any way to avoid so many try\catches?

Comment: One big try or add a throws clause to the enclosing function?

Comment: if i have one big try and, for ex. second item fails, i'll lose data about "afrer second" items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use not 'get' but 'opt' methods. Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#opt(java.lang.String)) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what library you are using for JSON parsing but you can try this .

First go to

1)http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

2) Paste your response

3)Select json in source type

4)Select Gson in Annotation style

5)Click on the preview

It will generate a modal class for you. 
And use Gson library to parse it.
You can add dependency for it in build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Now use below line to parse the json and wrap into your Modal class

```
YourModalClass value = GSON.fromJSON(jsonString, YourModalClass.class);
```